# Cannot invoke org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProviderInstance(Object) because this.providerFactory is null

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, resteasy

I'm Migrating my wildfly from 10 to 24 and I'm using the "wildfly-server-migration" tool for that.
Once it upgraded I'm trying to deploy my existing resteasy application in wildfly 24.
I have upgraded to wildfly 26 as well, still getting the same error.
I'm getting following error while the deployment.
I have updated the spring-jar from 3.1.5 to 4.7.6 in following location \modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-spring\main\bundled\resteasy-spring-jar
But that didn't work for me.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProviderInstance(Object)" because "this.providerFactory" is null
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:90)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProviderInstance(Object)" because "this.providerFactory" is null
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
            ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProviderInstance(Object)" because "this.providerFactory" is null
        at deployment.abcd-SNAPSHOT.war//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.ModuleProcessor.processInjector(ModuleProcessor.java:48)
        at deployment.abcd-SNAPSHOT.war//com.nexala.spectrum.rest.service.SpectrumContextListener.contextInitialized(SpectrumContextListener.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
        ... 10 more
```

Comment: Are you including RESTEasy in your deployment? WildFly 26 uses RESTEasy 3.15.1.Final FWIW.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Yes I'm using RESTEasy in my deployment, Seems I'm using the same versions.

Comment: You should not include RESTEasy in your deployment as it's already being provided by the server. Try removing the RESTEasy dependencies from your deployment.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, I have removed all the RESTEasy dependencies other than resteasy-guice, that needed for compile time.

Comment: Hi, get this fixed by adding adding this into jboss-deployment-structure.xml
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="microprofile-opentracing-smallrye" />
    </exclude-subsystems>

And did some code level changes too